# Jsf:image not upload destination place using IE9 browser and all other working fine

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I used simple mode,netbean,glassfish 3.0 and primefaces 3.0

Backing Bean

```
private UploadedFile file;
private String destination="D:\\temp\\";

public void upload(FleUploadEvent event) {
    System.out.println("upload");
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    try  {
        copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println("uploaf finished"); 

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
    try {
        // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
             out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("New file created!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my jsf page

```xml
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" sizeLimit="100000"/><br/>
```

Comment: Not related to your problem: move `System.out.println("uploaf finished");` in upload method or remove it.

Comment: above code working all browser fine but in IE9 browser in destination place the image is not uploaded why ?

Comment: i have stuck in this task last five hour plz help any body

Comment: luiggi Mendoza sir please help when upload the image destination place the following message show in consolve "D:\TEMP\C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ulcerimage.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" these image i keep on desktop and i am upload the D directory in TMP folder but IE9 browser not working

Comment: File upload in IE the file name would be absolute path. You'd have to trim the filename.

Comment: You have clear message about destination - D:\TEMP\C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ulcerimage.jpg is wrong path. Use path from file upload component, your code `File(destination + fileName)` is not correct.